# stochastic fubini theorem

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Take two stochastic processes: $X_t=\int_0^tx_sdW_S$ and $Y_t=\int_0^t y_sdW_s$, where $W_s$ is a standard Brownian motion. Let $Z_t=X_tY_t$, and consider the following integral $\int_0^1 Z_t dt$. We can use the stochastic Fubini theorem here to show that 
$$
\int_0^1 Z_t dt = \int_0^1 \int_0^tdZ_s dt = \int_0^1 (1-t)dZ_s
$$
But I can also rewrite $\int_0^1Z_tdt$ as $\int_0^1 \int_0^t X_t dY_s dt$. My question is can I now use the stochastic fubini theorem here to show
$$
\int_0^1 Z_t dt = \int_0^1 X_t\int_0^t dY_s dt = \int_0^1\int_t^1X_s dsdY_t 
$$ 
I am confused because the integrability conditions for the Fubini theorem seem to be satisfied but $\int_t^1X_sds$ is no longer adapted to the filtration $\sigma(W_s:s\leq t)$. Is such a change in the order still permitted? If not, can you please tell me why it fails? If it is, how do I show
$$
\int_0^1 (1-t)dZ_t = \int_0^1\int_t^1X_s dsdY_t 
$$

Comment: Maybe this helps? (probably not since the question never got an answer) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806376/how-to-prove-the-stochastic-fubini-theorem-exercise-2-19-in-chapter-iv-of-revu